# Cannot render well-formed html tables using Knockout.js templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I'm totally delighted with my first experiences with `Knockout.js`, brilliant library really, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around its templating features, for instance this very simple contacts application, where I'd like to generate a table row for each new contact:

```
<h3>Contact</h3>

<p>First Name: <input data-bind="value: contactFirstName" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input data-bind="value: contactLastName" /></p>
<p>Email Address: <input data-bind="value: contactEmailAddress" /></p>

<button data-bind="click: addContact">Add</button>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Email Address</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'contactsTemplate', foreach: contacts}" />
</table>

<script id="contactsTemplate" type="text/html">
  <tr>
    <td>${ $data.firstName }</td>
    <td>${ $data.lastName }</td>
    <td>${ $data.emailAddress }</td>
  </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function contact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress) {
        return {
            firstName: ko.observable(firstName),
            lastName : ko.observable(lastName),
            emailAddress: ko.observable(emailAddress)
        };
    }

    var viewModel = {
        contactFirstName: ko.observable("Peter"),
        contactLastName: ko.observable("Gibbons"),
        contactEmailAddress: ko.observable("peter.gibbons@initech.com"),
        equipments: ko.observableArray([new equipment("Peter", "Gibbons", "peter.gibbons@initech.com")]),
        addEquipment: function () {
            this.equipments.push(new equipment("Peter", "Gibbons", "peter.gibbons@initech.com"));
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

The bindings are working okay but I'm getting frustrated as it seems is nesting the whole new `<tr>` within the first `<td>`. It happens with both Iexplore and Firefox.

Any advice will be sincerely appreciated, thanks much in advance for your guidance.

**EDIT**

Updated markup to reflect **RP Niemeyer** contribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can replace this line:

```
<tr data-bind="template: {name: 'contactsTemplate', foreach: contacts}" />
```

with:

```
<tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'contactsTemplate', foreach: contacts}"></tbody>
```